# Unit testing asynchronous events

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing, asynchronous

I have a setup where changing a variable of a class raises an event run asynchronously that I'm trying to unit test.

```
class A {

    Action<int> OnIntChange;

    private int _a;
    public int a {
        set {
            OnIntChange(value);
        }
    }
}

class B {

    RaiseAsyncEvent(int value) {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {c = value;});
    }

    int c;
}
```

Previously everything was synchronous, so I could unit test pretty easily:

```
B b = new B();
A.OnIntChange += b.RaiseAsyncEvent;    
A.a = 10;
Assert.AreEqual(10, A.b.c);
```

However this fails now. I can't use [ManualResetEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) because I'm not directly raising this event and won't be able to without some restructuring of code. It seems my only option is to just add a System.Threading.Thread.Sleep() call after calling A.a = 10, but I'm looking for other options. Suggestions?

~~~~~~~~~~Edit~~~~~~~~

One potential solution I'm looking at is to have RaiseAsyncEvent return the task it creates and setting a field to that task. Something like:

```
class B {

    Task task;

    RaiseAsyncEvent(int value) {
        task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {c = value;});
    }

    int c;
}


B b = new B();
A.OnIntChange += b.RaiseAsyncEvent; 
b.task.Wait();
A.a = 10;
Assert.AreEqual(10, A.b.c);
```

~~~~~~~~~~Further Edit~~~~~~~~~~

What I ended up doing to solve this was changing B to the following:

```
class B {

    bool RunAsync = true;

    RaiseAsyncEvent(int value) {
        Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {c = value;});
        if(!RunAsync) { task.Wait();}
    }

    int c;
}
```

and changing the test to:

```
B b = new B();
b.RunAsync = false;
A.OnIntChange += b.RaiseAsyncEvent;    
A.a = 10;
Assert.AreEqual(10, A.b.c);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a [TaskScheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler(v=vs.110).aspx) in the constructor of B. A custom version of `TaskScheduler` can wait for the completion of all tasks in a unit test.

```
class B {
   public B(TaskScheduler taskScheduler)
   {
      _taskScheduler = taskScheduler;
   }   


   public B(): this(TaskScheduler.Default)
   {
   }


   public void RaiseAsyncEvent(int value)
   {
       Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {c = value;}, CancellationToken.None,
         TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, _taskScheduler);
   }

   TaskScheduler _taskScheduler;

}
```

[ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.concurrentexclusiveschedulerpair(v=vs.110).aspx) has the capability to wait for completion that we seek.

```
// Unit test

 var schedulerPair = new ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair();

 B b = new B(schedulerPair.ConcurrentScheduler);
 A.OnIntChange += b.RaiseAsyncEvent;    
 A.a = 10;

 schedulerPair.Complete();
 schedulerPair.Completion.Wait();

 Assert.AreEqual(10, A.b.c);
```

It scales to more advanced scenarios when you need to keep an eye on more than one async operation:

```
 B b1 = new B(schedulerPair.ConcurrentScheduler);
 B b2 = new B(schedulerPair.ConcurrentScheduler);
 B b3 = new B(schedulerPair.ConcurrentScheduler);

 A.OnIntChange += b1.RaiseAsyncEvent;    
 A.OnIntChange += b2.RaiseAsyncEvent;    
 A.OnIntChange += b3.RaiseAsyncEvent;    
 A.a = 10;

 schedulerPair.Complete();
 schedulerPair.Completion.Wait();

 Assert.AreEqual(10, b1.c);
 Assert.AreEqual(10, b2.c);
 Assert.AreEqual(10, b3.c);
```

EDIT:  `TaskScheduler` instance can also be shared using a static property, in this case `B` constructor signature does not change.

```
static class EventScheduler
{

  public static TaskScheduler TaskScheduler
  {
      get {return _taskScheduler; }
      set {_taskScheduler = value; }
  }   

  static TaskScheduler _taskScheduler = TaskScheduler.Default;

  public static Task RunAsync(Action<T> action)
  {
      return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {c = value;}, 
       CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach,
      _taskScheduler);
   }
}

class B 
{
   public void RaiseAsyncEvent(int value)
   {
       EventScheduler.RunAsync(()=>{c = value;});
   }
 }

 // Unit test

 var schedulerPair = new ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair();
 EventScheduler.TaskScheduler = schedulerPair.ConcurrentScheduler;

 B b = new B();
 A.OnIntChange += b.RaiseAsyncEvent;    
 A.a = 10;

 schedulerPair.Complete();
 schedulerPair.Completion.Wait();

 Assert.AreEqual(10, A.b.c);
```

Comment: I like this answer and I'm marking it as the accepted answer - if I absolutely had to take care of my problem in the way I asked, this would be right.

However what I ended up doing was forcing the tasks to run synchronously by adding a "RunAsync" bool field on B, adding   

if(!RunAsync) {
task.wait();
}  

inside RaiseAsyncEvent, and setting b.RunAsync = false; in the TestInitialize. Not the prettiest, but it's a simple fix to what could have been a really complicated problem.

Comment: If you want to avoid changing the constructor signature consider a static instance of TaskScheduler (a singleton) shared by all events. Then instead of setting RunAsync property on all objects you just assign ConcurrentScheduler to the static property.

Comment: The code I'm working with is far more complex than I could show here- I'm actually implementing my own static CallbackManager that I pass an event into and it generates a new Task that's run async or synchronously depending on a couple factors, saves the handle, and deals with return logic. The bool I'm adding in allows me to just bypass the async logic and force it to be synchronized from the start which let all my unit tests still pass. Since the manager is static I don't need anything more than a single change to its RunAsync bool at the beginning of the test and it'll be run fine.